# wix pass INSTALLLOCATION to my Edit control in custom dialog before PublishProduct

Tags: properties, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to pass a value to my custom dialog in Edit control

```
<Control Type="Edit" Id="mdir" Width="153" Height="15" X="206" Y="82" Property="MDIR"/>
<Property Id="MDIR" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]"/>
```

Have error:

```
The 'MDIR' Property contains '[INSTALLLOCATION]' in its value which is an illegal reference to another property.
```

How pass value Installlocation to Edit? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The message means that there is definition of INSTALLLOCATION anywhere, so without more detail it's not obvious how to answer this. If you're using one of the WiX UI choices then maybe you need INSTALLFOLDER. Where do you expect the INSTALLLOCATION property to be initialized?

Your dialog sequencing isn't clear either, Is it intended to process the the chosen install location after it's entered by the user?

Comment: В другом диалоге пути заменяется. Почему я не могу использовать одну и ту же схему?

Comment: <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION"/>